# Why is my Custom Interceptor not getting Initialized?

Tags: java, security, websphere, interceptor

I am trying to develop and deploy a custom Trust Association Interceptor on Websphere Application Server. Did the below steps

- Created a class implementing TrustAssociationInterceptor interface and its methods
- Created a JAR and placed it under lib/ext folder of the server directory
- Created an entry of my custom interceptor class in the "Global Security -> Web and SIP Security -> Trust associations -> Interceptors", enabled the interceptor (checkbox) and restarted the server.

Cannot find the Sysout I have put in the initialize method of my custom interceptor anywhere in any logs including server start/stop logs, sysout logs or trace logs.
Not able to figure out which configuration is getting missed out.
Also, do I need to add any custom properties in the custom interceptor class when adding it to the Interceptor list?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Below is the Custom TAI code

```
public class CustomSSOTAI implements TrustAssociationInterceptor {

private static final String CUSTOM_TAI_VERSION = "1.0.0";
private static final String CUSTOM_TAI_TYPE = "Custom Trust Association Interceptor";

@Override
public void cleanup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside cleanup Method #####*****");
}

@Override
public String getType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside getType Method #####*****");
    return CUSTOM_TAI_TYPE;
}

@Override
public String getVersion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside getVersion Method #####*****");
    return CUSTOM_TAI_VERSION;
}

@Override
public int initialize(Properties arg0) throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside initialize Method #####*****");
    System.out.println("*****##### Initializing Custom SSO TAI #####*****");
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isTargetInterceptor(HttpServletRequest arg0) throws WebTrustAssociationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Entering isTargetInterceptor Method #####*****");

    System.out.println("Determining if this TAI should handle the incoming request...");

    if (arg0.getParameter("callCustomInterceptor") != null) {
        System.out.println("callCustomInterceptor: " + arg0.getParameter("callCustomInterceptor"));
        System.out.println("Custom SSO TAI is being used to establish trust!");
        return true;
    }

    System.out.println("Bypassing Custom SSO TAI, did not find a user ID in the request");
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Exiting isTargetInterceptor Method #####*****");

    return false;
}

@Override
public TAIResult negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
        throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Entering negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust Method #####*****");
    String userId = arg0.getParameter("uid");
    if (userId.equals("portalUser")) {
        System.out.println("*********** CustomSSOTAI *****************");
        System.out.println("UserID = " + userId);
        return TAIResult.create(SipServletResponse.SC_OK, userId);
    }

    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Exiting negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust Method #####*****");
    return TAIResult.create(SipServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, userId);
}
```

}

**Warm Regards,**
*Ekansh*

Comment: Do you have Administrative and Application security enabled?

Comment: Yes, both Administrative and Application security are enabled

Comment: That should work, can you add code - class definition, and init method to the question (remove bodies of other methods you have).

Comment: Thanks, have added the code of the init method. Also would like to mention that the WAS version I'm using is 8.0.5 Is custom TAI supported for this version?

Answer (score 0):

TAIs are supported in all WAS versions including 8.0.5. You are doing all correct, but just to make sure:

- verify that you have full package class name in TAI config, like: `com.company.CustomSSOTAI`
- once again click `Enable interceptros`, save and restart. I know you did it ;-)

Once restarted you should see in the `SystemOut.log` messages about other TAIs also (if you didnt remove them). Check this, your TAI is loaded:

```
[9/22/17 13:58:11:885 CEST] 00000000 SystemOut     O com.tivoli.pd.as.jacc.cfg.TAMConfigService initialize() About to initialize PDAdmin with the value C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer80\tivoli\tam
[9/22/17 13:58:11:947 CEST] 00000000 TrustAssociat A   SECJ0121I: Trust Association Init class com.ibm.ws.security.web.TAMTrustAssociationInterceptorPlus loaded successfully
...
[9/22/17 13:58:11:963 CEST] 00000000 TrustAssociat A   SECJ0121I: Trust Association Init class com.ibm.ws.security.spnego.TrustAssociationInterceptorImpl loaded successfully
...
[9/22/17 13:58:12:010 CEST] 00000000 TrustAssociat A   SECJ0121I: Trust Association Init class gas.tai.CustomTAI loaded successfully
[9/22/17 13:58:12:010 CEST] 00000000 SystemOut     O *****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside initialize Method #####*****
[9/22/17 13:58:12:010 CEST] 00000000 SystemOut     O *****##### Initializing Custom SSO TAI #####*****
[9/22/17 13:58:12:010 CEST] 00000000 TrustAssociat A   SECJ0122I: Trust Association Init Interceptor signature: v1.0
[9/22/17 13:58:12:010 CEST] 00000000 distSecurityC I   SECJ0240I: Security service initialization completed successfully
```

Hope it helps.